# Desire2Learn Valence API, PUT CourseOffering 404

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Based on the information here http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#actions I would expect that to 'update' a courseOffering I would specify a PUT with a CourseOfferingInfo block, which only contains a few attributes.  Every time I try this, I get a 404, not found - even using the same route for a successful GET (404 says org doesn't exist OR org is not an offering - neither is true).  However, if I specify a CreateCourseOffering block (directly from a previous GET), the PUT works fine.  Is this correct and the documentation not?  Or are there other things I should look for in this scenario?  The documentation says use CreateCourseOffering for the POST to create an offering… I simply want to update one attribute of that offering and as such thought the PUT was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ["create" POST route](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#post--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-courses-) with a [`CreateCourseOffering`](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#Course.CreateCourseOffering) block, this will create a new course offering, and send back the CourseOffering block for the newly created course offering (this will include the org unit ID value for the new org unit you've built).

If you want to update an existing course offering, you should, as you suspected, use the ["update" PUT route](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#put--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-courses-%28orgUnitId%29) with a [`CourseOfferingInfo`](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#Course.CourseOfferingInfo) block. Note that you must provide valid information for *all* the fields in this block, since when used successfully, the LMS will use all the properties you specify in that block for new values for the org unit. The `StartDate` and `EndDate` fields are particularly finicky: you must provide *either* a valid [`UTCDateTime`](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/conventions.html#term-utcdatetime) value (notice that the three-digit millisecond specifier in these values is mandatory) *or* a JSON `null` value if the field is not applicable.

**Why a 404?** What you're seeing with the 404s and the data you're passing is likely down to the way the back-end service is doing data binding. It tries to de-serialize your provided JSON data (and query parameters) into data objects it can read/manipulate -- if you provide a JSON block that contains a superset of the properties it's expecting, then this may work (for example, if you provide a `CourseOffering` block when you're expected to provide a `CourseOfferingInfo`) as the binding layer may ignore fields it doesn't need. If the binding process fails, because you provide a value for a property that can't be bound to the data type expected, or because you fail to provide a JSON property field it expects, then this can cause the service to return a 404 (because binding/de-serializing incoming parameterized data happens at the same time as matching the URL route to an underlying service handler).

If you provide a JSON structure (and query parameters) that the web-service *can* bind to its expected data objects, but the *values* you provide are invalid or nonsensical, then this can cause the underlying service handler to respond with a 400 (signalling an Invalid Request). But in order to get this far, your parameterized data still needs to get properly deserialized and bound into data objects for the underlying service to examine.

We'll be [updating the documentation](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/apicall.html#disposition-and-error-handling) to more explicitly draw out this fact. The safest policy from the calling client perspective is to pass valid JSON structures that are exactly what's expected by the individual routes, especially since the underlying back-end service implementation might change how it handles incoming requests.